# Setting model attribute var from inside javascript function spring boot thymeleaf js

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a quantity incrementor html that was made with javascript and html. I can't set the value of the quantity model attribute from within the thymeleaf html page.

This is the code of the html

```
<div class="product_quantity clearfix">
                            <span>Qty</span>
                            <input id="quantity_input" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" th:value="${quantity}">
                            <div class="quantity_buttons">
                                <div id="quantity_inc_button" class="quantity_inc quantity_control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                <div id="quantity_dec_button" class="quantity_dec quantity_control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This is the code of the javascript that increments the values

```
    function initQuantity()
{
    // Handle product quantity input
    if($('.product_quantity').length)
    {
        var input = $('#quantity_input');
        var incButton = $('#quantity_inc_button');
        var decButton = $('#quantity_dec_button');

        var originalVal;
        var endVal;

        incButton.on('click', function()
        {
            originalVal = input.val();

            endVal = parseFloat(originalVal) + 1;
            input.val(endVal);

        });

        decButton.on('click', function()
        {
            originalVal = input.val();


            if(originalVal > 0)
            {
                endVal = parseFloat(originalVal) - 1;
                input.val(endVal);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The model attribute is accessed from ${quantity} but it doesn't change as the values are incremented.

Comment: and what does it have to do with the Java language?

Comment: model attribute is in java controller. Using java spring

Comment: Where/how are you calling your `initFunction`? I would expect to see buttons with click handlers `onclick="initQuantity()"`. (And I think this question does not relate to Java or Thymeleaf - just HTML and jQuery.)

Comment: It works as expected like when i console log endVal it displays the correct value but i cant set the quantity model attribute to endVal